# How do I get jquery to recognize created on the fly element with .on?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code I am using to begin an animation process:

```
$('body').on('click','#contain span', function(){
            var $target = $(this).parent().children('#contain_inner');
            flyout.fadeOldBox($target);
            flyout.createBox();
})
```

`flyout.createbox()` then creates a new instance of `#contain_inner` but that new instance is not available when my click function above tries to target it again. I know that if I were to use `.live` things would work but that is deprecated now and I don't really understand how I would use `.on` to accomplish what I need here.

I know I am using `.on` above already for the click, but I still don't understand how to bind it to the new `#contain_inner` div that will be create in `flyout.createBox()`.

EDIT: showing flyout.createBox() code...all is working now!

```
createBox: function(){
            $box = $('<div id="feed_contain_inner"></div>'); //was accidentally creating that as div class= instead of the id
            $box.load('example')
            $box.appendTo('#contain');
            flyout.positionBox($box);

    }
```

Comment: You're using multiple IDs by the sounds of it. Use classes.

Comment: what does flyout.fadeOldBox actaully do.. is it a plugin ?? if yes can u post the link??

Comment: Where is the new div#contain_inner instance getting created..? I mean under which parent..? You should ideally share the flyout.createBox() code that is causing the problem too..

Comment: @kent...I was about to share the flyout.createBox code when I realized the problem. I was creating the new div with the class="container_inner" and not div id, so everything is working fine now. But I will post the flyout.createBox anyways.

Answer (score 1):

This is the same as live:

```
$(document).on('click', '.yourslector', callback);
```

Answer (score -1):

Are you setting your `.on()` inside `$(document).ready()`? It will only trigger on new elements if it's set *outside* `$(document).ready()`.